# How to ask sympy to don't translate bm to boldsymbol?

Tags: python, latex, sympy, pprint

I'm in the situation where the enduser can define a variable name by himself.

For instance: a variable called "tbm_al" is correct.

In order to pprint variable as latex, I'm using sympy.latex and expecting to have something like "tbm" with "al" as indice, but bm is translated in boldsymbol.

[image]

Is there a way to have both "tbm" with indice "al" and neither t (bold) with indice al nor tbm_al as string ?

like:

\begin{equation*}\begin{equation}**{tbm}_{al}**\end{equation}\end{equation*}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This autotranslation of `bm` is performed by the [Sympy latex printer](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/_modules/sympy/printing/latex.html) (`sympy.printing.latex`), specifically as `bm` is an entry in the variable modifiers dictionary `modifier_dict` declared in `sympy.printing.latex`. I see no way in the source to disable the use of the modifier dict upon call `latex(expr, **settings)`; from what I can see, not settings are not used anywhere in the same context as the `modifier_dict` dictionary.

Have a look at e.g. the function `translate(s)` in the source:

> `def translate(s):`
>
> Check for a modifier ending the string.  If present, convert the
>       modifier to latex and translate the rest recursively.
>
> ...

From the source of this function, it's quite clear that the modifier dictionary *will* be checked (recursively) for all entries in the argument expression.

---

The remaining option would then be to manually modify the name modifiers (`modifier_dict`) in your own custom source copy of `sympy.printing.latex` (or, alternatively, in the original), by simply removing the dictionary entry for key `bm`. This is, of course, unless you want to make use of `bm` elsewhere.

See also:

- http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/printing.html#sympy.printing.latex.latex

Comment: I used a decorator to decorate the latex function.

Comment: @user2652620 that seems like a valid workaround, good job. As a note: a "less intrusive" method would be to only modify parts of the dictionary, rather than wiping all of it.

Answer (score 1):

Thx to @dfri. I decided to clear modifier_dict during latex translate.

```
from sympy.printing.latex import modifier_dict
from sympy import latex
def cancel_sympy_translate(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        saved_dict = dict(modifier_dict)
        modifier_dict.clear()
        result = f(*args, **kwargs)
        modifier_dict.update(saved_dict)
        return result
    return wrapper

latex = cancel_sympy_translate(latex)

t = Symbol("tbm_al")
print latex(t, mode="equation")
```

\begin{equation}tbm_{al}\end{equation}

with the "keep_translate_keys". (suggested by @dfri)

```
def cancel_sympy_translate(f, keep_translate_keys=None):

    keep_translate_keys = keep_translate_keys or []

    def remove_unwanted_keys(modif_dict):
        for k in modif_dict.keys():
            if k in keep_translate_keys:
                continue
            del modif_dict[k]

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        saved_dict = dict(modifier_dict)
        remove_unwanted_keys(modifier_dict)
        result = f(*args, **kwargs)
        modifier_dict.update(saved_dict)
        return result

    return wrapper

latex = cancel_sympy_translate(latex, keep_translate_keys=["bar"])
t = Symbol("tbm_abar")
print latex(t, mode="equation")
```

\begin{equation}tbm_{\bar{a}}\end{equation}